# Can't determine cause of mystery segfault

Tags: c, memory

The following code was something I was working on to demonstrate some object-oriented programming ideas in C. I'm getting a segfault though. No warnings or errors. Mavericks apparently broke valgrind and gdb no longer comes with xcode, so I was stuck debugging this with printfs.

I think I tracked the error to the line:

```
strcpy(b->genre, genre);
```

in the function "book_create." Apologies if this is something dumb, C isn't really a language I spend a whole lot of time in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct book {
    char *title;
    char *author;
    char *genre;
    char *isbn;
    void (* set_title)(struct book *, char *);
    void (* print)(struct book *);
} * Book;

void book_set_title(Book self, char *title) {
    free(self->title);
    self->title = (char *) malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
    strcpy(self->title, title);
}

void book_print(Book b) {
    printf("Title: %s\nAuthor: %s\nGenre: %s\nISBN: %s\n", b->title, b->author, b->genre, b->isbn);
}

Book book_create(char *title, char *author, char *genre, char *isbn) {
    Book b = (Book) malloc(sizeof(Book));
    b->title = (char *) malloc(strlen(title) + 1);
    b->author = (char *) malloc(strlen(author) + 1);
    b->genre = (char *) malloc(strlen(genre) + 1);
    b->isbn = (char *) malloc(strlen(isbn) + 1);
    strcpy(b->title, title);
    strcpy(b->author, author);
    strcpy(b->genre, genre);
    strcpy(b->isbn, isbn);
    b->set_title = book_set_title;
    b->print = book_print;
    return b;
}

void book_destroy(Book b) {
    free(b->title);
    free(b->author);
    free(b->genre);
    free(b->isbn);
    free(b);
}

int main() {
    Book b = book_create("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", "JK Rowling", "Fantasy", "123456");
    b->set_title(b, "Yo momma");
    b->print(b);
    book_destroy(b);
}
```

Comment: You cast a pointer to a struct. Which is weird to begin with. And then you started writing to the struct as if it was a pointer.

Comment: `Book b = (Book) malloc(sizeof(Book));` change to `Book b = (Book) malloc(sizeof(book));` note small book in sizeof

Comment: @SteveCox Is that really that weird? I was taking a cue from OOP languages in that objects are always pass by reference. I figured I'd hide the pointer in the typedef. If it's not idiomatic C, thanks.

Comment: IMHO `typedef struct book *Book;` is bad habit. Use `typedef struct book Book;`  and declare `Book*b;` you really want to see at once what is a pointer!

Comment: @JoshInfiesto hiding pointers behind typedefs is very strange

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch That makes sense now that I think about it. Pointers are very important to C's semantics, and I probably made a mistake when I decided to hide it with a typedef.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits A little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
Book b = (Book) malloc(sizeof(Book));
```

`Book` is pointer to `struct book`, so you allocate too small amount of memory. You should use:

```
struct book *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
```

In C it is better not to cast the result of malloc, and typedefed pointers to structs can be misleading as you could have seen.

Comment: Yep. As soon as this was pointed out, it became obvious. Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(*Book)` doesnt compile

Comment: @SteveCox Yes I modified my code and replaced *Book with struct book

Comment: Suggest 1) Avoid creating typedef of pointers.  2) `struct book *b = malloc(sizeof *b);`.  Less error prone and easier to maintain.

Comment: @chux Edited to incorporate your suggestions